# How to have a variable persist between Heroku dyno/server restarts and new deployments?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, dyno

I have an array that has a bunch of values that I want to persist between dyno restarts and deployments of new code. In the below example, 'arrayWithValues' is the array that I am trying to have persist, but whenever the server is somehow restarted, it wipes it back to being an empty array. I'm using a Node.js based server that can be seen below:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json());

http.arrayWithValues = []

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.send(http.arrayWithValues)
});

app.post('/', function(request, response) {
  var data = JSON.stringify(request.body);
  http.arrayWithValues.push(data)
  response.send(http.arrayWithValues)
});

http.listen(port, () => console.log('listening on port ' + port));
```

Answer (score 1):

Data locally saved does not survive a Dyno restart because the Heroku File System is [ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem).
The solution is to use an external service like a DB or remote file storage.

For saving files you can check [Files on Heroku](https://medium.com/geekculture/files-on-heroku-cd09509ed285) where you can see various options:

- Amazon S3 is a very popular solution
- For simple files saved occasionally you can even consider using GitHub
- DropBox is also a viable option